# cffile upload location

Tags: coldfusion, cffile, enctype

In CF7, can anyone tell me if there's a way around the file being automatically uploaded to the /tmp/ folder before being moved to a destination location I provide?  I'm trying to use cffile in a shared server location.  I don't have access to the tmp directory, and am hoping to find a work around.

```
 <cffile action="upload" destination="#expandpath('./')#/myFiles" fileField="myFile">
```

I'm working in a Linux environment, and like I said, have no access outside my webroot.  The oddest part is that I seem to not make it to this point.  From my  I get a 500 page or directory not found error.  Even if the post.cfm does NOT have any code, just text, so it seems that the problem is coming from the enctype is trying to "place" the file on the server before I ever get to .

I'm at a total loss and hopeful someone can help.

Comment: Don't think temp dir dest can be changed. See similar error with temp dir http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/forums/messages.cfm?threadid=C62A8E02-0979-C907-4DEF4169A5664AFE They said that hosting admin fixed it. Think you need to continue kicking admins ass.

Comment: Just thought. Maybe it is just sandbox restriction? 
Would be stupid to forbid uploads on hosting, but this should be re-checked.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00001766.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that where the file is uploaded is actually a function of the webserver, not CF itself.  CF copies/moves/etc. the file from the temp directory once it is on the server.  You will have to get the server admin to allow your process access to the directory.

Comment: Yep, thats what I found.  Godaddy will not allow access to write to the /tmp directory in a shared environment.  Understandable to an extent I suppose.  But, I went with CrystalTech, they allow it, have CF8 vs CF7 w/ Godaddy.  And is cheaper.